# Integration test with a configuration file

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a integration test that uses nUnit and has a setup like

```
[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    var webHostBuilder = new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>();
    TestServer = new TestServer(webHostBuilder);
}
```

'Startup' is the Startup class for the web application that I hope to test. Like other ASP.NET application this startup looks like:

```
        /// 
        /// Startup constructor with DI, auto generated
        /// 
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }


        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }


        ///
        /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        /// auto generated
        /// For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        //// 
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
// I would like Configuration to access the same configuration values that are read into the web
// application but somehow Configuration points elsewhere.
        }
```

I would like Configuration to access the same configuration values that are read into the web
application but somehow Configuration points elsewhere. Can anyone offer me a hint to how I can
have Configuration point to the same configuration (appSettings.json) that is read in during normal
execution of the web application?
Thank you

Comment: Could you please share the details codes about the TestServer class?

Comment: The TestServer class is pulled in as part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost NuGetPackage under the same namespace. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-3.1